# Office 2016 on OS 10.11.6 - any known conflicts in 2017?

Tags: macos, ms-office

MacBook Pro Quad i7 late 2011, 16GB Ram, SSD
OS 10.11.6 (latest El Capitan)
Running Office for Mac 2011 (registered)
Use: graphic / web design / video commercial

I have opportunity to install MS Office 2016 FOC through my employment scheme and they are keen for me to do this to match Win team.

Q. Any known issues or incompatibilities with my specific OS please?

I don't need help with install and I am aware of issue on first release of 10.11 which is now fixed with Apple update. Looking for someone running same set-up to confirm solid.

Checked web and forums but 95% swamped with early issues that are not relevant in 2017.

Comment: I think it will run fine. There have been some updates that should fix some bugs. I think that most bugs are out of the software now. Where I work there aren't coming much customers with questions about office on their Mac. Although we have had one customer where outlook would freeze after a few minutes, but he uses an Macbook. Reinstalling office or macOS/OS X didn't work. I don't know how this problem is solved

Comment: Excellent. I take an average on reported faults and ignore one-offs. I've been installing Macs for 20yrs and appreciate that (many) errors are down to poor user knowledge and ill considered or applied updates.

Comment: You should be aware that some stuff in Office 2011 is missing in 2016, and Retail versions of 2016 are missing some things in the 365 subscription version.  Have a look at the MS Word forum.   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, Microsoft is investing substantial engineering, funding, resources, man and woman-power in to the Office 365 - Mac Office 2016 suite.

The updates are very rapid, easy access to pre-release and insider builds, well documented issues / workarounds.

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_for_mac_support_team_blog/
- https://products.office.com/en-us/mac/latest-office-for-mac
- https://products.office.com/en-US/mac/microsoft-office-for-mac

There's even a ["back channel" admin and version tracking system](https://macadmins.software) that helps point power users to what changes when with respect to Office for Mac.

[Are there known issues - absolutely](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-Outlook-for-Mac-54afa5e3-db38-422a-9d94-3b55330ded8e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Even better, Microsoft documents them so people don't waste time troubleshooting things. Will one or more affect you? That's harder to tell, but we have thousands of daily users in our company using these apps heavily. The number of things we need to escalate to MS are few and far between and the time to fix things is superb. I personally prefer iWork suite, but Office and Microsoft have a huge lead from what I can see for most people's needs in the office space - Mac or iOS.

Comment: I totally agree with bmike. Also, at the risk of stating the obvious, no-one can give you a 100% guarantee because every system has its own quirks (depending on configuration, installed software, connected hardware, etc). For future reference, a good resource to check software compatibility with versions of macOS is the [Roaring Apps](https://roaringapps.com) website.

Comment: Update: Marked as answered. I have installed now and can CONFIRM running fine. Appreciate all input. Having been at this for 18 years Mac and Win, I concur that every system is different and a stray font, update, plugin etc can crock an individual setup. In this case, I wanted to short cut my usual 2 day clean install of a new OS / apps as I had a great deal of work on. Happy with OS 10.11 and running rapidly on a crucial SSD with 16GB Ram (even though MacBook is 6 years old!).